# How to push object into relation collection in seeds.rb

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby-on-rails-4

I have three models: **Match**, **Broadcast** and **Channel**. **Match** and *Channel* are associated with `has_many :through` relation.

In rails console it's possible to do `Match.find(3) << Channel.find(1)` but in `seeds.rb` this line do nothing after running `rake db:seed`.

How to add object to collection in seeds file?

#### Edit:

It was typo. I forgot to add `.channels`. Line should look like this:
`Match.find(3).channels << Channel.find(1)`.

Comment: How exactly are your associations setup in your models? Share the specific code.

Comment: I'm guessing it should look like this: `Match.find(3).channels << Channel.find(1)`.

Comment: @ChrisPeters thank you! I forgot to write ```.channels``` in ```seeds.rb```

Comment: You're welcome. I've submitted the comment as an answer so you can upvote that and accept it instead of the guy who swooped in and took credit an hour later. :D

Answer (score 0, accepted):

you could do something like this in your **db/seeds.rb**

`Match.find(3).channels << Channel.find(1)`

its important to note that you have to include the 'channels' after the find

Happy Codding

Answer (score 1):

I'm guessing it should look like this so that you're adding the `Channel` record to the `channels` relation instead of the main `Match` record:

```
Match.find(3).channels << Channel.find(1)
```

Comment: Your answer is identical to mine